# I suddenly started getting no such table after APK update in play store

Tags: android, android-sqlite

My App was working perfectly in play store without any Database crash I have updated a new version with FirebaseJobDispatcher for scheduling background jobs instead of AlarmManager. I started getting reports from play store

> SQLiteException: no such table:

none of the tables are accessible.

I am getting no such table for all table but DB file is there.  I have never deleted any table from my code.

Not able to reproduce this use case in my development scenario, What could be the reason for this issue?

Can this Code accidentally delete my all tables ?

```
public int deleteTopFromReportingTable(int count) {
        int deletedRows = -1;

        try {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "deleteTopFromReportingTable: " + "delete count=" + count);
            SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "ROWID IN" + "(" + "SELECT ROWID FROM " + TABLE_USER_EVENTS + " ORDER BY ROWID ASC LIMIT " + count + "" + ")";
            deletedRows = mSqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE_USER_EVENTS, query, null);
            Logger.debug(TAG, "deleteTopFromReportingTable: " + "Records deleted size=" + deletedRows);

            return deletedRows;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return deletedRows;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Post your db handler code.

Comment: Have you added any new Table in last release?

Comment: I have not added or deleted any column in latest release it is same like already running in play store . I have changed only background job management.

Comment: I  have just extracted Database file by some hacks  in a debug version , I can see I have .db file but no table inside it . How can It happen , Not able to think this  use case .